# Create a column based on index that represents Calendar-day difference between two consecutive trading days

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have trading data that have a date as its index.

[image]

I want to create a new column that makes it compute the difference between the consecutive dates as follow

[image]

I created the following code to do so

```
df2=df1.reset_index(drop=False).copy()
df2['Date_lag']=df2.Date.shift()
df2['NT_diff'] = (df2['Date'] - df2['Date_lag']).dt.days
df2=df2.loc[:, df2.columns != 'Date_lag']
df2=df2.set_index('Date')
df2.head()
```

However, I am sure that there is an easier way to do this by a simpler code. May you please advise on this matter.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use timedelta64 built in function in numpy as follow

## Calendar-day difference between two consecutive trading days

```
df1['date']=df1.index
df1['NT_diff'] = np.abs((df1['date'] - df1['date'].shift(1))/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
df1=df1.loc[:, df1.columns != 'date']
df1.head()
```

This should give you the result you are looking for.